# Installing fuzzyfinder vim plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, fuzzyfinder

I unziped the vim-fuzzyfinder and vim-l9 packages in my ~/.vimrc directory

```
[shetye@dev03 ~/.vim/vim-fuzzyfinder]$ls
autoload  doc  plugin
[shetye@dev03 ~/.vim]$cd vim-l9/
[shetye@dev03 ~/.vim/vim-l9]$ls
autoload  doc  plugin
```

Also i tried copying the same in my home directory. vim however does not detect this plugin.

```
:fuf-usage
E492: Not an editor command fuf-usage

:FufBuffer
E492: Not an editor command FufBuffer
```

I tried adding the directory ~/.vim/vim-fuzzyfinder, ~/.vim/vim-l9 to the $PATH env variable. That did not help either.

Any ideas on how to get fuzzyfinder going ?

Comment: I highly recommend you to use pathogen or vundle to manage your plugins, that structures the `~/.vim` directory tree way more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You should install it correctly to make it work. This is the file structure you should have:

```
~/
+-.vim/
 +-autoload/
 +-doc/
 +-plugin/
```

Once you get to that point, you are supposed to type this command in Vim:

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.vim` directory structure that you have created is a mix between traditional Vim (where all plugins are mixed together into single `.vim/autoload/`, `.vim/plugin/`, etc. directories) and the separation (into `.vim/bundle/<pluginname>/autoload/`) created by package managers like *Pathogen* or *Vundle*.

Either stick to the original layout (even though there are many proponents for the new package structure, the old one works just fine; it's just not as easy to uninstall a plugin), or install one of the mentioned package managers and adhere to their prescribed layout.